# Cannot update embedded child VC from non-parent VC

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicontainerview, viewdidappear

Up to date Xcode/Swift/iOS.

I have a Master VC (called StartVC) that contains a Child VC (called TopBarVC) via and embedded segue. The Child VC contains a button, that, when pressed, modally segues to a 3rd VC (called CategoryPickerOverlayVC) (the view in this VC serves as a dropdown box for picking a category).

```
    @IBAction func CategoryFilterButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toCategoryPickerOverlay", sender: self)

}
```

When an option is selected from the dropdown box, which itself is composed of three buttons, the title of the selected button should be used to replace the title text of the button in the Child VC.

In the Master VC, I use prepareforsegue to store a reference to the Child VC in a variable - "topBarReference" - at the moment when the embed segue takes place.

```
 var topBarReference: TopBarVC?


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {        
    if segue.identifier == "TopBarPane"{
        topBarReference = segue.destination as? TopBarVC
    }
}
```

Then, in the 3rd VC, when I click on one of the button options in the dropdown box, the button title is sent via a prepareforsegue to update the button in the Child VC (via "topBarReference").

```
        if segue.identifier == "unwindToStartVC"{

        let vc = segue.destination as! StartVC

        vc.topBarReference?.filterButtonText = ((sender as! UIButton).titleLabel?.text)!

    }
```

The 3rd VC then unwind segues back to the Master VC. I should add that when the button in the Child VC is changed, a variable (filterButtonText) in Child VC is first set with the title text and then this variable is then used to set the button title text via the viewDidAppear method of Child VC.

When using the debugger, I also note that viewDidAppear in the Master VC does not seem to execute after unwinding (I placed a diagnostic print-to-console in viewDidAppear and nothing prints after the unwind segue). I realise this would explain the button not getting updated but I've got no idea why viewDidAppear does not run.

I have also tried using a delegate protocol and  instantiateViewController(withString:) to no avail. All of the methods produce the same result, which is that the button in the Child VC does not get updated. No errors are shown. Everything else happens as expected.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: if both of them are "embedded" into the StartVC, that is the StartVC is still being seen, then view did appear will not be called. 

Try using notifications. 

Make your startVC listen for a specific notification and send that out when you unwind / select an option from the dropdown. 

Inside your notification handler code, update the button title

Comment: The 3rd VC is a seperate VC, not embedded.

Comment: "I've got no idea why viewDidAppear does not run" Because it never disappeared. I think that is what @ShawnFrank told you as well.

Comment: @Rossco, to try the Shawn Frank's comment, you can test in the `Master VC`'s viewDidDisappear method , if execute when perform segue.

Comment: @Shawn Frank: Thanks for reply - I have not yet used notifications (although I am aware of them) so will be looking that up at some point. I was confident-ish that my original code SHOULD be working so was looking for someone to point out why it wasn't, rather than going straight to changing the mechanism for updating the button text.

Comment: @Matt: Shawn was asking (as I interpreted it) if both the Child and 3rd VC's were embedded in the Master VC, which is not the case. The 3rd VC was a seperate VC displayed over the top of everything else via a modal segue so why would the Master VC view not disappear? Is that some aspect of modal segues I am not yet aware of? The background of the 3rd VC was set to transparent - would this perhaps mean that the Start VC view "behind" the Child VC view, did not disappear per se, and hence viewDidAppear of Start VC wouldn't trigger when the 3rd VC disappeared via the unwind segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have found that my original code works fine bar one line in the prepareforsegue of the Child VC. If I change that prepareforsegue from:

```
        if segue.identifier == "unwindToStartVC"{

        let vc = segue.destination as! StartVC
        vc.topBarReference?.CategoryFilterButton.titleLabel?.text = ((sender as! UIButton).titleLabel?.text)!

    }
```

to this:

```
        if segue.identifier == "unwindToStartVC"{

        let vc = segue.destination as! StartVC
        vc.topBarReference?.CategoryFilterButton.setTitle((sender as! UIButton).titleLabel?.text, for: .normal)

    }
```

it works just fine. The use of the .setTitle method seems to make a difference although I am not sure why.

Thanks to Matt for giving me the idea to change it to that. Matt's method did work when i tried it, although, as I am unwinding to the Master VC and not the Child VC, I had to edit the code accordingly, in terms of where I placed it.

As my little "discovery" equates to the smallest change to the original code, I'll mark this as the answer.

Thanks to all for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

If so, the solution I used was very simple: the third VC uses `prepareForSegue` to set a property of the embedded VC, and the embedded VC picks up that property in the `unwind` method.

In my implementation, the three view controllers are called ViewController, ChildViewController, and ThirdViewController. This is the *entire* code (everything else is configured in the storyboard):

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var theButton: UIButton!
    var buttonTitle : String?

    @IBAction func unwind(_:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        self.theButton.setTitle(self.buttonTitle, for: .normal)
    }

}
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        (segue.destination as! ChildViewController).buttonTitle = (sender as! UIButton).currentTitle
    }

}
```